# Резиновая верстка в Unity

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-ui

Есть канвас в юнити,  внутри него панель, которая растягивается на всю ширину и высоту канваса, на ней компонент horizontal layout group. Внутри нее три панели с компонентами layout element с параметром flexible width 33,3. Тоесть панели должны занимать по ширине примерно одинаковое расстояние. Они так и работают, но если добавить на любую из них компонент horizontal layout group и поместить в нее например raw image, то ширина данной панели изменяется, она начинает занимать по ширине больше чем остальные, в чем может быть причина? Не понимаю причину такого поведения, ведь по логике ее размер контролируется родителем, а не содержимым, разве нет?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Когда внутри панели с компонентом Horizontal Layout Group добавляется другой компонент, например, Raw Image, ширина данной панели может измениться и начать занимать больше места, чем остальные. Это происходит потому, что компонент Horizontal Layout Group пытается адаптировать размеры своих дочерних элементов, чтобы они соответствовали его настройкам. Если добавленный компонент имеет большую ширину, то Horizontal Layout Group может увеличить ширину родительской панели, чтобы компонент поместился внутри нее.

Компонент Horizontal Layout Group позволяет размещать дочерние элементы рядом друг с другом, а также настраивать их размеры и выравнивание. Если установлен параметр flexible width у дочерних элементов, то они будут занимать примерно одинаковое расстояние по ширине.

Если необходимо ограничить максимальную ширину компонента, можно использовать параметр preferred width/height, установив flexible width/height в 0.

В целом, изменение размеров панели с компонентом Horizontal Layout Group может быть вызвано различными факторами, включая настройки компонента и размеры его дочерних элементов.